# Entity Framework is throwing "System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException" for some users

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to delete user tables and user config table,it is working fine most of the time,but for some users, it is throwing an `OptimisticConcurrencyException` with this message:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

This is my code:

```
var context = UnitOfWork._context;

var userToRemove = context.Users.Where(<some_condition>).ToList();

var userConfigurationsToRemove = (some_condition_with_users_join_on_userConfig).ToList();

if (userToRemove != null && userToRemove.Any())
{
    context.Users.RemoveRange(userToRemove );

    if (userConfigurationsToRemove != null && userConfigurationsToRemove.Any())
    {                         
        context.userConfigurations.RemoveRange(userConfigurationsToRemove );
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My question is: `users` table is a child table and `userConfigurations` is parent table, can I do save changes twice; one after `context.Users.RemoveRange(userToRemove );` and other after `context.userConfigurations.RemoveRange(userConfigurationsToRemove)`, or is there anything else that can be done?

This issue is coming once in a day for some anonymous users.

Comment: its up to you how you want to handle it.

Comment: @DanielA.White-I am not able to find any solution for this

Comment: The error states that the user has already been removed. This could happen with a race condition like a double click or 2 users removing the same record at the exact same time. How you want to handle it is up to you. You can wrap this code in a try/catch and log the error and continue as if no error occurred (as an example).

Comment: As a side note `ToList` will never return `null` so you do not need to do a check on `== null`.

Comment: @lgor -each user has individual record and double click will not happen everyday 3-4 times,i mean this issue is coming everyday for some users,does writing context.savechanges twice can helps,because I am suspecting that It will be deleting user and userconfiguration tables concurently and it may cause foreign key constratint error.